# Writing to existing Sales_data object in std::vector causes program to crash (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, containers

I'm reading and doing the exercises in Stanley Lippman's C++ Primer Ed.5.

I'm having the following issue with my code: when I update an existing `Sales_data` object in the `std::vector<Sales_data> vec;`, the program crashes.

In order to overcome this, I erase the existing `Sales_data` object and replace it with a new updated object.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this without erasing the `Sales_data` object and then replacing it?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
struct Sales_data
{
    std::string isbn() const{ return this->bookNo; }

    Sales_data& combine(const Sales_data &rhs)
    {
        this->units_sold += rhs.units_sold;
        this->revenue += rhs.revenue*rhs.units_sold;
        return *this;
    }

    Sales_data add(const Sales_data &lhs, const Sales_data &rhs)
    {
        Sales_data sum =lhs;
        sum.combine(rhs);
        return sum;
    }

    std::string bookNo;
    unsigned units_sold =0;
    double revenue =0.0;
};


int main()
{
    Sales_data book;
    std::vector<Sales_data> vec;

        while(std::cin>>book.bookNo>>book.units_sold>>book.revenue)
        {
            for(auto it =vec.begin(); !vec.empty()&&it!=vec.end(); ++it)
            {
                if(book.bookNo == it->isbn()) //Check to see if book exists if vec 
                {
                    Sales_data add_book =it->add(*it, book);

                    vec.erase(it); //must erase to prevent a crash
                    vec.push_back(add_book);
            
                }
            }
          //Some code for new Sales_data entry
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`vec.erase(it);` invalidates `it`, so when the loop continues, you have undefined behaviour.

> Is there a more efficient way of doing this without erasing the Sales_data object and then replacing it?

Yes, use `combine` instead of `add`.

Aside: can you use standard algorithms, i.e. [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

```
while(std::cin >> book.bookNo >> book.units_sold >> book.revenue) {
    auto it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](auto & other){ return book.isbn() == other.isbn(); });
    if (it != vec.end()) {
        it->combine(book);
    } else {
        vec.push_back(book);
    }
}
```

I'd also suggest moving your inputing into `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream & is, Sales_data & data)`.

Comment: Thank you Caleth.

Answer (score 1):

You're not allowed to modify a collection as you're iterating over it.
This is exemplified by `push_back`: occasionally it can decide to resize the backing vector, which makes `it` point to now-invalid memory and the resulting symptom is a crash. Calling `erase` first prevents the array from growing, but also invalidates `it` which has annoying side effects.

In this case, the correct solution is to overwrite the contents of the iterator in place:

```
*it = it->add(*it, book);
```

Or you can call `combine` directly:

```
it->combine(book);
```

Or you could choose to override `operator+=` and get:

```
*it += book;
```

Comment: *'now-uninitialised memory'* – wouldn't that mean that there's still memory available? I'd prefer *'invalid memory'*.

Comment: That's better, yes.

Comment: Thank you Botje.